# How to get the month name from a number in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a variable containing a month number. How can I get the name of the month from this value?

I know I could define an array for `$month_num => $month_name`, but I want to know if there is a time function in PHP that can do this, without the need for an array?

Comment: [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is good enough?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$monthnumber,1,2011));
```

Comment: Although, this is the right answer, there should be an explanation of what's going on.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24596827/1563422) below for a slightly shorter way of doing this.

Answer (score 16):

You can get just the textual month of a Unix time stamp with the `F` [**`date()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format character, and you can turn almost any format of date into a Unix time stamp with [**strtotime()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), so pick any year and a day 1 to 28 (so it's present in all 12 months) and do:

```
$written_month = date("F", strtotime("2001-$number_month-1"));

// Example - Note: The year and day are immaterial:
// 'April' == date("F", strtotime("2001-4-1"));
```

[**Working example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Zxdwt4)

The nice thing about using `strtotime()` is that it is very flexible. So let's say you want an array of textual month names that starts one month from whenever the script is run;

```
<?php
for ($number = 1; $number < 13; ++$number) {

    // strtotime() understands the format "+x months"
    $array[] = date("F", strtotime("+$number months"));
}
?>
```

[**Working example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/srda8h)

Comment: An excellent idea, though the result starts from next month forward, which may not be the standard (Jan, feb, etc) output we'd expect..

Answer (score 7):

A slightly shorter version of the accepted answer is:

```
date('F', strtotime("2000-$monthnumber-01"));
```

- `F` stands for "month name", per the table on [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).
- The `2000` is just a filler for the year, and the `01` a filler for the day; since we're not concerned about anything other than the month name.

Here's [a demo](http://ideone.com/gXPmVt) on ideone.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use:

```
jdmonthname(gregoriantojd($monthnumber, 1, 1), CAL_MONTH_GREGORIAN_LONG)
```

It's just another way. I don't know anything about the efficiency of this compared to [@Dreaded semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6971148/2041318)'s answer.

Here's [a demo](http://ideone.com/gxkesq) on ideone.

For reference:

- [`jdmonthame`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.jdmonthname.php) returns the Julian calendar month name.
- [`gregoriantojd`](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.gregoriantojd.php) converts a Gregorian (currently used) calendar date to Julian (the `1, 1` part stands for day and year).

Answer (score 0):

use the function mktime which takes the date elements as parameters.

```
<?php
 $month_number= 3;
 $month_name = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month_number, 10));
 echo $month_name; 
?>
```

Output:
**March**