# How can I convert date from 8 to AUG

Tags: php

I would like to convert the number to actual month. I only need a month.

I am now trying like this

`$str = 8;`
`$anInt = intval($str);`
`$test = date('M',$anInt);`
`echo $test;`

the result is JAN, I was supposed to get "AUG" as a result. I dont know why.

any idea or suggestion for me?

Comment: What exactly does `date` accepts as a second argument? Please check it in the documentation

Comment: My answer edited to show you your exact example.

Answer (score 2):

The `date()` function assumes a timestamp.

You should try this:

```
$test = date('M',mktime(0,0,0,$anInt,0,0);
```

From the docs for [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [mktime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php):

```
// Prints: Your date's month is : August
echo "Your date's month is : " . date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $anInt, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mktime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).

```
echo date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
echo date('M',strtotime('08/01/2012'));
```

Or, if you want all caps:

```
echo strtoupper(date('M',strtotime('08/01/2012')));
```

There might be other approaches to this, but this was the first to come to mind

Comment: NOTE: is this 8th of January of 1st August? I suggest Y-m-d format instead.

Comment: Fair enough, I have my ini set to the `m/d/Y` format, should have pointed that out

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question. [Read here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971135/get-monthname-in-php)

Read about date function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

using `date()` you should use timestamp.
To convert date value to timestamp, use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$date = '2012-8-8';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
echo date('M',$timestamp);
```

For your problem:

```
$monthnumber = 4;
$date = '2012-'.$monthnumber.'-8';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
echo date('M',$timestamp);
```